# adl command line turned silent

Tags: air

I am starting to develop a new air/html/ajax application today and for some reason my trace() output is not being printed to the console window anymore. Plus, I am also not getting any error messages printed for syntax errors or runtime errors. I tried this on a different machine and there was no problem, so it must have been something wrong with this particular machine. I was thinking it had to do with me using the flex 3 sdk, but removing that from my path variable did not help, neither did reinstalling the air sdk. If anyone has encountered this before, help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is not specific to the debugger player.  The availability of trace statements in the console from ADL is dependent on whether or not any one of the following settings are turned on in your `mm.cfg` file:

- `ErrorReportingEnable`
- `TraceOutputFileEnable`

Either one of those will block trace output in the console window - `stderr` I believe - and instead (in the case of `TraceOutputFileEnable`) redirect it to a log file.

More information about `mm.cfg` is available [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fc9.html).

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It is because I installed the flash debug player. Now the error messages all go the the log file where the debug player writes to.